# RESTful web-service created using Tonic only works in web-browser

Tags: web-services, apache

I coded this API for this web-software that consumes web-services. Now, I have tested some other API's with this software, and it does consume them successfully but it doesn't consume mine - error 405 Method Not Allowed.

Mine works fine in web-browser. Browser is using GET I'm guessing, which it does allow. The other API's I tested did allow POST, but not PUT. Maybe the web-software is using POST? I have no way of knowing.

So, just to test things I opened my Tonic file and then copied-pasted my function, renamed it and marked it down as POST as follows and restarted apache:

```
  /**
         * @method POST
         * @accepts str
         * @return str
         */
        public function helloFunctionTest()
        {
           ...
        }
```

Simple REST Client is still showing POST as unavailable. What am I missing?